# Is there a way to add more text fields to useraccounts package?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, meteor-accounts

I am currently using the useraccounts:bootstrap package on localhost. I am just trying to find a way to add more text fields to the sign up page because just email, password, and verify password isn't enough. I am trying to add fields such as: address, phone number, and some other things. I know it sounds like an easy task, but I when through all the package files and I couldn't seem to find a file that was used to add text fields.

My project is on github via the link: https://github.com/Aggr0vatE/testbasichelp

And the live version of the website is here: testbasic.meteor.com/home

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, figured it out by using the AccountsTemplates.addField(options) and it was all good.